# SyntaxError: name 'x' is used prior to global declaration

Tags: python, random, global-variables

I want to create a programm which should get random strings of an array and put it inside a sentence. The problem is that the first sentence has to be different to the next sentence. Therefore I tried to use a global variable which should store the previous sentence, because otherwise it would be overwritten. But now I get an

```
SyntaxError: name 'previous_sentence' is used prior to global declaration
```

I hope you can help me

```
import random

previous_sentence = ''

def create_sentence():
    names = ["x", "y", "z"]
    designations = ["a", "b", "c"]
    sentence = '' 
    while sentence == previous_sentence:
        name = random.choice(names)
        designation = random.choice(designations)
        sentence = f'{name} ist ein {designation}'
    global previous_sentence
    previous_sentence = sentence
    return sentence

for i in range(10):
            print(create_sentence())
```

Comment: You don't have `vorheriger_satz` in your code - please translate all parts together.

Comment: Your code can't produce that error, as it never uses the name `vorheriger_satz` *anywhere*. However, you *are* using the name `previous_sentence` before the `global previous_sentence` statement. `global` affects the *entire* scope it occurs in, not just the statements following it. (Presumably, you want the `global` statement at the beginning of the function either way.)

Comment: Better yet, though: don't use a global variable at all. Pass the previous sentence as an argument to `create_sentence` and save the return value: `previous_sentence = create_sentence(previous_sentence)`.

Comment: yes sorry, I translated it to english

Answer (score 0):

because you use `previous_sentence` in `while`

```
def create_sentence():
    ...
    while sentence == previous_sentence:
        ...
    global previous_sentence
```

but makes global after

so move `global previous_sentence` at start of function or before you first use in `while`

```
def create_sentence():
    global previous_sentence
    ...
```